# How to get only the jsonb of specific keys from postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm aware that you can remove keys from a jsonb in postgres using something like this

```
select '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3}'::jsonb -'a';
 ?column?
----------
{"b": 2 "c":3}
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to only grab specific keys? Like let's say I just want to get the key-value pair of just the `'a'` key.

Something like this?

```
select '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'::jsonb + 'a' + 'b';
 ?column?
----------
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
(1 row)
```

EDIT: Changed the example to to show that I'd like to grab multiple keys-value pairs from the jsonb and not just one pair.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can filter down to a single key fairly easily like so:

```
jsonb_object(ARRAY[key, jsonb_data -> key])
```

...or you can filter down to multiple keys:

```
(SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value) FROM jsonb_each(jsonb_data) WHERE key IN ('a', 'b'))
```

Or on a more complex condition, if you want:

```
(
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
  FROM jsonb_each(jsonb_data)
  WHERE
    key NOT LIKE '__%'
    AND jsonb_typeof(value) != 'null'
)
```

These kinds of questions can be answered very easily by simply reading the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: Do you know how to grab the jsonb from a specific table? such as `column from table`?

Comment: Yes, these are just example expressions you can use in your returned columns.

Comment: For example, `SELECT jsonb_object(ARRAY['a', jsonb_data -> 'a']) FROM table;`

Answer (score 8):

I actually found that this way works to.

```
select jsonb_build_object('key', column->'key') from table;
```

reference:
https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/73auce/new_user_to_postgres_can_i_grab_multiple_keys_of/

Comment: An important point to mention that you can have multiple keys here like so: `jsonb_build_object('a', column->'a', 'b', column->'b')`

Answer (score 6):

You can do this

```
SELECT jsonb_column->>'key_name_here' as 'alias_name_as_you_like' from table_name
```

In the case of the query asked above, it would be

```
select '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3}'::jsonb->>'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

Paraphrasing the situation

> we have a jsonb value and multiple keys in mind, `a` and `c`
>
> ```
> select '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3}'::jsonb - '{a,c}'::text[];
> ```
>
> `-` is a tidy operator but gives us the opposite of what you want
>
> ```
> {"b": 2}
> ```

solution is to wrap that in `array(select jsonb_object_keys(...))` and perform the `-` again

```
select '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3}'::jsonb - array(select jsonb_object_keys('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3}'::jsonb - '{a,c}'::text[]));
```

you get a json *with only* those keys, `a` and `c`

```
{"a": 1, "c": 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get just the value like so:

```
 select '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'::jsonb-> 'a';
```

If you must, you can transform that back into jsonb manually, or perhaps go through an array, hstore or other intermediate type. Here's the "manual" way

```
 select ('{ "a": '||('{"a": 1, "b": 2}'::jsonb->'a')::text||'}')::jsonb
```

Comment: That does work, is there anyways to grab multiple keys without needing to store it within a new select variable? Like just to have it be a new jsonb?

Comment: You should not be reconstructing json/jsonb objects like this. There are functions available [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to do what you are trying to do, namely `jsonb_object()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter multiple rows with JSONB documents in each of them:

```
-- Let's generate rows with JSONB column:
WITH s AS (SELECT generate_series(1, 100) num),
g AS (SELECT num, jsonb_build_object('a', s.num, 'b', s.num * 2) obj FROM s),

-- A "filter" adding (in my example only keys of "filter" document remain in result rows)
j AS (SELECT '{"a": "int", "c": "string"}'::jsonb AS filter),
a AS (SELECT (ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_object_keys(filter))) AS ar FROM j),

-- Useless keys removing
o AS (SELECT jsonb_object_agg(l.key, l.value) obj
        FROM g, LATERAL jsonb_each(g.obj) l, a 
        WHERE l.key = ANY(a.ar)
        GROUP BY num)

SELECT * FROM o ORDER BY obj->'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Begin;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (id  serial, jdoc jsonb);
    insert into test(jdoc) values('{"a": {"b":"foo"}}');
    insert into test(jdoc) values('{"a": "test"}');
    insert into test(jdoc) values('{"a":[2,3,4]}');
    insert into test(jdoc) values('{"b":[2,3,4]}');
  commit;
```

`select (jdoc->'a') from test where jdoc ? 'a'`
will get all the specific key's value.
If you want JSONB of the specific key: `select jdoc from test where jdoc ? 'a'`