# How to only keep properties from a Postgres jsonb object that exist in an array of keys?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a `jsonb` object with numerous properties, and I have a Postgres array of keys that I want to extract from the object, into a new, stripped-down object.

If my object is:

```
'{"foo": true, "bar": 2, "baz": "cat", "other": "Some text"}'::jsonb
```

and my array of properties to extract is `'{foo,other}'`, my desired result is:

```
'{"foo": true, "other": "Some text"}'::jsonb
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46497457/14660)...

```
select jsonb_object_agg(key,value)
from jsonb_each('{"foo": true, "bar": 2, "baz": "cat", "other": "Some text"}'::jsonb)
where key = any('{foo,other}')
```

[`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) turns the JSON into a table of `key` (text) and `value` (jsonb) columns which can then be queried normally.

[`where key = any('{foo,other}')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) is basically `where key in ('foo', 'other')` but for arrays.

Finally [`jsonb_object_agg(key,value)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) aggregates all the matched rows into one JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(elem.key, elem.val)
FROM (jsonb_each(
         JSONB '{"foo": true, "bar": 2, "baz": "cat", "other": "Some text"}'
     ) AS elem(key, val)
   JOIN (unnest(
            TEXT[] '{foo,other}'
        ) AS filter(key) USING (key);
```