# How to properly get the value of specific keys from postgres. Also remove null

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Populate Data.

```
Begin;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (id  serial, jdoc jsonb);
    insert into test(jdoc) values('{"a": {"b":"foo"}}');
    insert into test(jdoc) values('{"a": "test"}');
    insert into test(jdoc) values('{"a":[2,3,4]}');
    insert into test(jdoc) values('{"b":[2,3,4]}');
    commit;
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494856/how-to-get-only-the-jsonb-of-specific-keys-from-postgres) answer,  `SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value) FROM jsonb_each(SELECT (jdoc->'a') from test) WHERE key IN ('a'));` But this query not working. Encounted error.

```
 SELECT (jdoc->'a') from test;
```

Will filter out the value that include key 'a'. But this query returns 4 rows. Expect only 3 rows. Since only 3 rows meet the criteria. So How to properly get only the jsonb of specific keys from postgres?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to get the rows that contain the key `a` use the`?` operator

```
select *
from test 
where jdoc ? 'a'
```

Comment: `select (jdoc->'a') from test where jdoc ? 'a'` This way works...